# Console based consumer for dockerized kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api, messagebroker

I have docker container running kafka. Once I push the message I want to run a console based consumer and listen from the particular topic. is there any way to do that?

Comment: The `kafka-console-consumer` tool from the Kafka distribution works, though it may require some tweaking.  Have you already tried that?  Is there a specific error you're encountering?

Comment: What version of Kafka you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Cheatsheet FYR,

**Console Producer & Consumer**

```
kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper localhost:2181/kafka --topic  topic_name --from-beginning
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic_name
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181/kafka --list
```

**Topic details & Deleting topic**

```
kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181/kafka --topic topic_name
kafka-configs --zookeeper localhost:2181/kafka --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name topic_name --add-config retention.ms=1000
kafka-topics --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181/kafka --topic topic_name
```

**Check active brokers**

```
zookeeper-shell localhost:2181/kafka ls /brokers/ids
```

**KafkaCat**

```
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -L | grep topic
kafkacat -C -b localhost:9092 -o -5 -t topic_name
```